# Merging frames with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 240fps video and I want to merge/average every 4 frames into 1, resulting in a 60fps video with a motion blur type effect. Any ideas how I can do this with ffmpeg?

Comment: Something like this: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/16552?

Comment: Almost, but I want to slow my input video down x4. Like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LpvEEk67iE4. The guy says he achieved the effect "by recording the game on 240fps and then merging every 4 frames into one". This is what I'm trying to do

Comment: That's what the command does.

Comment: That command speeds the video up and keeps the fps the same as the input